# Flutter: Setting --dart-define when debugging android native

Tags: android, flutter

When running my flutter app in the usual way, I can set `--dart-define=VAR=val` in Android Studio as "Additional run args". In order to debug my Android native code, I  open the "android" directory using Android Studio, and start debugging from there. How can I set those variables when debugging native code?

Comment: Did you found the solution for this?